# If the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded and $\lim(a_n-a_(n+1))=0$, then is $(a_n)$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to prove or disprove the following, If the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded and $\lim(a_n-a_(n+1))=0$, then $(a_n)$ is a convergent sequence.
I tried multiple examples to disprove it however I keep getting stuck with it. I saw in another post that if $(a_{n+1}−a_n)→0$
and $(a_n)$ is bounded, then $(a_n)$ isn't convergent, but I can't find a counter example to prove it.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following sequence: $a_n=(-1)^n$. It is trivially bounded and not convergent.